# Use << operator with pointer to char

Tags: c++, pointers, char

There is an operator overload for `<<` which interprets `char*` as a C-style string. If `char*` however points to a single character, how do I output it into a stream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `ch` is of type `char*` and actually points to a single char, use `*ch` so that the type of the expression is `char`. The operator will know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c=42;//sadly I could not use my favourite constant 666
char* pc=&c;
cout << *pc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char x = 'a';
char *p = &x;
stream << *p;
```

Comment: care to expand upon this answer?

Comment: @Code Monkey: What's there to expand?

Comment: Your post came through as a low quality post per the SO automatic engine. I'd imagine you could add more to your answer such as an explanation.

Comment: @Code Monkey: I really don't care what an automatic engine thinks of my answer. If you agree with the engine, please flag this as "very low quality" or "not an answer" and let the moderators remove it, if they agree with you. I personally think this code snippet answers the OP's question perfectly well. Words are redundant.

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive. Done!

Comment: Code Monkey: Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

For that case you'd need to overload `<<` for `char` (no `*`) and dereference your `char*` before using it in the expression.

Comment: -1, not only is this not necessary, it's also disallowed. You should only overload operators where at least one of the two arguments is a type you defined.

Comment: No one said what type (or whose) was being used on the other side of the operand.